# set jquery delay in jquery form serialize variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, serialization, opencart

This is my simple code for adding products in cart using ajax but when user clicked too fast then some of products are not added in cart.
At the first line i fetch data from form using serializing after calling ajax and add product in cart.
Now give me solution for it where i can put timeout or delay and something similar so execution halt for sometimes.

```
var datas = form.serialize();

            if(usefancy){
                $.fancybox.showActivity();
            }

            $.getJSON(vmSiteurl+'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&nosef=1&view=cart&task=addJS&format=json'+vmLang,encodeURIComponent(datas),
            function(datas, textStatus) {
                if(datas.stat ==1){

                    var txt = datas.msg;
                } else if(datas.stat ==2){
                    var txt = datas.msg +"<H4>"+form.find(".pname").val()+"</H4>";
                } else {
                    var txt = "<H4>"+vmCartError+"</H4>"+datas.msg;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in a function:

```
var datas = '';
setTimeout(function(){
    datas=form.serialize();
},1000);
```

**Better approach**

Find and event that triggers when the user finishes adding products (maybe a button clicked or something of the kind) and make the serialization and the ajax call then.

Supposing you have a button with id="sendProduct"

```
<button id="sendProduct">Send product</button>
```

you could do something like:

```
$("#sendProduct").click(function () {// Everytime user clicks "sendProduct" you will send info to the server.
    var datas = form.serialize();

    if (usefancy) {
        $.fancybox.showActivity();
    }

    $.getJSON(vmSiteurl + 'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&nosef=1&view=cart&task=addJS&format=json' + vmLang, encodeURIComponent(datas),

    function (datas, textStatus) {
        if (datas.stat == 1) {
            var txt = datas.msg;
        } else if (datas.stat == 2) {
            var txt = datas.msg + "<H4>" + form.find(".pname").val() + "</H4>";
        } else {
            var txt = "<H4>" + vmCartError + "</H4>" + datas.msg;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i have another question related to above question,this is a right way means is it possible to set delay in variable

Comment: This means that after a second, datas will contain the value of the form serialized. I don't know exactly what your problem is, depending on the problem this could be a solution or not.

Comment: Actually problem is that i have jquery ajax to add product in cart when user add product slowly then all working fine but when user in hurry some of product did not added in cart.
i was thinking if i set delay in assign variable then problem should be solved.

Comment: Find and event that triggers when the user finishes adding products (maybe a button clicked or something of the kind) and make the ajax call then.

Comment: Do you want to send an ajax request everytime your users add a product or only when they've finished adding products? Do they click a button when they add a product/finish adding?

Comment: Every time send request to ajax when user click on product.

Comment: OK,Now i am going to check and

Answer (score 0):

```
   setTimeout(function(){
       var datas = form.serialize();
    }, 3000);
```

Were 3000 is equivalent of 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

Using `setTimeout` is a very unreliable way of updating variables(What if the jQuery function could not execute even in maybe 3 seconds?). Rather you should use the `callback` functionality available in many `jQuery` functions and set the variable in that `callback` function.

**EDIT** : For the issue with user clicking too fast, you must implement a simple locking mechanism so that while an item is being added to the cart, the "add to cart" option is disabled. This could be done as:

```
var cartLock = false;     //means you can add items to cart
```

Since, you need the ability to capture the `complete`, I would recommend the following approach,

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: function(msg){
        cartLock = true;                 // Just before calling
      },
      success: function(msg){
        // your logic here
      },
      complete: function(){
        cartLock = false;                // After request completes
      }
    });
```

Now, one final check you need to introduce is that, you will only call `$.ajax()` when `cartLock` is `false`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I have updated the answer for the rapid clicking issue. Rest should work fine. Accept the answer if it solves your problem.